# Rethinking Python for loop to pySpark to create dataframes

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I have a list of accounts which I iterate in a loop calling the details from an API function `get_accounts`. The JSON response for each call includes details for one account with one or more contacts which I add to dataframes `df_accounts` and `df_contacts` respectively.

The API loop portion works though it takes a long time. The volume of data is under 5K accounts and 10K contacts. The final goal is to save two delta tables one for all accounts and one contacts. I know there **must be a better approach** utilizing pySpark architecture.

```
account_details = [] 
provider_details = [] 

for account_id in account_header['providerAccounts']:
    account_detail = get_accounts(account_id['id'])

    account_details.append(spark.createDataFrame(data = [account_detail['providerAccount']], schema=account_schema))

    for provider in account_detail['providerAccount']['providers']:
        provider_details.append(spark.createDataFrame(data = [provider], schema=provider_schema))


df_account = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, account_details)
df_provider = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, provider_details)
```

However an error occurs when I try to save the dataframes as a delta tables.

```
df_accounts.write.format("delta").mode('overwrite').save(acct_fulldeltapath)
df_provider.write.format("delta").mode('overwrite').save(px_fulldeltapath)
```

Error code below:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-7b487f51> in <module>
      4 px_fulldeltapath = pathFormatted + px_pathSparkSubFolderFull
      5 
----> 6 df_contacts.write.format("delta").mode('overwrite').save(px_fulldeltapath)

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in save(self, path, format, mode, partitionBy, **options)
    738             self._jwrite.save()
    739         else:
--> 740             self._jwrite.save(path)
    741 
    742     @since(1.4)

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1319 
   1320         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321         return_value = get_return_value(
   1322             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1323 

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o63219.save.

...

Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Total size of serialized results of 14638 tasks (4.0 GiB) is bigger than spark.driver.maxResultSize (4.0 GiB)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2464)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2413)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2412)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
```

Comment: Please post the root cause which will be deep down the stacktrace.

Comment: @AzharKhan I added the Caused by output. Thank you

Comment: I would suggest you create an array of dataframes to hold the values of each account and contacts instead of unioning it to the same variable as it would create a long DAG.. Once you have an array of dataframes union them to a single dataframe variable and save it as delta table... This would be efficient than what you are doing.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya The array approach helped create the df faster, but still faced the same error when writing the delta table. 

for contacts in account_detail['accounts']['contacts']:
      contacts_details.append(spark.createDataFrame(data = [provider], schema=provider_schema))


df_contacts = reduce(DataFrame.unionAll, contacts_details)


df_contacts .write.format("delta").mode('overwrite').save(px_fulldeltapath)

Comment: @AlenGiliana can you please update the question with the full code that you have written using the array approach. I still still you might be doing something in a different way..

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya The code is updated.

Comment: @AlenGiliana does directly using reduce this way works to combine or perform union on all the dataframes..
Something similar to this might work : 
from functools import reduce
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame
from typing import List

def unionMultipleDf(DfList: List) -> DataFrame:
  """
  """
  # create anonymous function with unionByName
  unionDfWithMissingColumns = lambda dfa, dfb: dfa.unionByName(dfb, allowMissingColumns=True)
  # use reduce to combine all the dataframes
  finalDf = reduce(unionDfWithMissingColumns, DfList)
  return finalDf

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya I'm able to create create the dataframes and reduce into a single dataframe without error. I run into a problem when I try to overwrite the delta table with the new combined dataframe.

Is there a better way to overwrite or update the delta table than what I have proposed?

Comment: @AlenGiliana if that does not work try to save it in chunks.

Comment: Not sure how to attempt that. @NikunjKakadiya If you're available for a screenshare session, happy to compensate for your time.

Comment: Sure. How would you like to connect? Email me on nikunjkakadiya2010@gmail.com